# Why are unmanaged target objects in a one-to-many relationship not causing IllegalStateException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

According to [Pro JPA 2](https://a.co/d/6hpsDDi)

> Ideally, during a flush all the objects pointed to by a managed entity will also be
> managed entities themselves. If this is not the case, the next thing we need to be aware
> of is the PERSIST cascade setting. If the relationship has this setting, target objects in the
> relationship will also be persisted, making them managed before the flush completes.
> If the PERSIST cascade option is not set, an IllegalStateException exception will be
> thrown whenever the target of the relationship is not managed, except in the special case
> related to one-to-one and many-to-one relationships

**Example to test my understanding of this**

I created the following two entities and service class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int id;
            
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee") //no persist cascade
    private Collection<Phone> phones;
    
    public Employee(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String number;
    
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;
}

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager cmEntityManager;

    @Transactional
    public Employee persistEmployee(Phone p) {
        cmEntityManager.detach(p); // it should already be detached but make sure
        
        Employee e = new Employee(1);
        e.setName("Bob");
        e.setDepartment(dept);
        e.setPhones(Collections.singleton(p));
        cmEntityManager.persist(e); //why is exception not thrown?                  
        cmEntityManager.flush();
        return e;
    }
```

**Breaking the above book quote down into steps**

> Ideally, during a flush all the objects pointed to by a managed entity will also be
> managed entities themselves.

In my service code above, I have `cmEntityManager.detach(p);` followed by `cmEntityManager.flush();`. So, phone is not a managed entity.

So, I need to be aware of the PERSIST cascade setting per this:

> If this is not the case [i.e., one of the objects, p, is not managed], the next thing we need to be aware of is the PERSIST cascade setting.

OK. I'm aware :). Next the book states:

> If the relationship has this setting [i.e., PERSIST], target objects in the relationship will also be persisted, making them managed before the flush completes.

The target object in the relationship between `Employee` and `Phone` is `p` which is a `Phone` entity. From my code, you can see that the relationship does **not** contain the cascade `PERSIST` setting:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee") //no persist cascade
private Collection<Phone> phones;
```

So, per the book:

> If the PERSIST cascade option is not set, an IllegalStateException exception will be thrown whenever the target of the relationship is not managed,

OK. `PERSIST` cascade option is not set. Therefore, an `IllegalStateException` should be thrown.

I should get the exception... Right? But wait the book goes on to say:

> except in the special case related to one-to-one and many-to-one relationships

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee") //no persist cascade
private Collection<Phone> phones;
```

Ah. So yes, I should get the exception... but I do **not**. Instead, the `Employee` object, `e` is silently flushed and then committed to the DB without a relationship to `p`. That is, the `p` row in the`Phone` table doesn't have a FK referencing the `e` row in the `Employee` table.

Is my understanding incorrect or is the book incorrect?

Comment: `Employee` does not own the relationship so it doesn't care about persisting it. You could add a `Cascade` but I prefer not to. It results in possibly/probably horrible SQL statements. It is better to persist the `Phones` yourself. Think of the `ManyToOne` relationship as query only.

Comment: @K.Nicholas - Thanks for you comment and advice. That makes sense but I'm trying to reconcile with what I've read in Pro JPA 2. Is the book wrong? Even if I create a new unmanaged Phone entity and set that on `Employee`, I don't get `IllegalStateException` when persisting the `Employee`.

Comment: You will only get hibernate exceptions if the phones collection is wrapped by a hibernate proxy class. You have not made any calls to hibernate before the persist so there will be no hibernate wrapping classes.

Comment: @K.Nicholas - Got it. I suppose the book is wrong then, because it doesn't stipulate anything about the exception being specific to entities that are proxied or even that it is specific to a particular persistence provider.

Comment: Perhaps the book statement only applies to unidirectional relationships. I noticed that if I remove the `mappedBy` element from the `Employee` `phones` attribute and remove the `Phone` `employee` attribute, I get the behavior (i.e., exception) as described by the book.

Comment: Probably not. They seem to be talking about cascade. Below you get the exception because there is no cascade and the employee, once saved by JPA, realizes there is a relation (a phone instance) that needs attention when you try to save it again with merge, but again, since it doesn't own it and there is no cascade, it cannot know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you an `IllegalStateException` but I don't know if this is what the book is trying to get at.

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager cmEntityManager;

    @Transactional
    public Employee persistEmployee(Phone p) {
        cmEntityManager.detach(p); // it should already be detached but make sure

        Employee e = new Employee(1);
        cmEntityManager.persist(e); //why is exception not thrown?
        e.setPhones(Collections.singleton(p));
        p.setEmployee(e);
        cmEntityManager.merge(e);
        return e;
    }
}
```

You can see hibernate talking about the proxy class in the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.example.jpaplay.JpaPlayApplication.main(JpaPlayApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.jpaplay.Phone with id 0
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1096) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:586) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:750) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy80.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.jpaplay.EmployeeService.persistEmployee(EmployeeService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.jpaplay.EmployeeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4d27e8b7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at com.example.jpaplay.EmployeeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a8c17225.persistEmployee(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.jpaplay.JpaPlayApplication.run(JpaPlayApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. I tried your code with `@OneToMany(mappdeBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` annotated on the `phones` attribute of `Employee`. I get `IllegalStateException` as you have noted in your answer. However, the book states that I should only get the exception when the target object is not managed and `CascadeType.PERSIST` is **not** specified Furthermore, the book at this point hasn't even covered the `merge` operation.

Comment: LOL, it's always something. `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` for merge. Also, `new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(p))` since it doesn't like the immutable collection.

Comment: Ah, yes... that makes sense. I changed cascade type to `MERGE` (and the collection type). I don't get an exception though. The book is referring to `PERSIST` operations rather than merging. The lead author of the book, Mike Keith, wrote the book several years ago for JPA 2.0. The book was updated for JPA 2.1 and 2.2 but was done by other authors . I wonder if JPA 2.0 changed this behavior but the book wasn't properly updated to reflect that change.

Comment: Short answer, no. It's also important to remember that JPA is more complicated than seems at first glance and there are a crazy amount of combinations and a lot of subtle differences between them which is too difficult to cover in a book that needs to cover all the big topics. I tend to preach that it's better to stay away from options and really get a handle on what JPA is meant to do for you and how to take advantage of those features.

Comment: Thanks. That's great advice. I'm trying to confirm my understanding of the book with the hopes of gaining deeper knowledge of JPA. To that end, I may create test examples of crazy scenarios that I would never do in production but will nonetheless be very useful in furthering my understanding on the JPA topic at hand. I revised my OP with the hopes of better clarifying that. If I'm wrong I've learned something, but if the book is wrong, I've still learned something and can kindly suggest an erratum to the authors (for the benefit of future readers).